# difference of two columns of dates

Tags: r, date, dataframe

I have a data frame let's say named "data" in R where 2 of the columns are dates in the form mm.dd.yyyy . I have to calculate the difference in days between those two columns in days. So, I need to calculate the difference between data$fd and data$ld. Does anyone know how do I do that?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
fd <- c('12.12.1971','11.01.1972')
ld <- c('04.03.2016','01.01.2017')

as.Date(ld,format = '%m.%d.%Y')-as.Date(fd,format = '%m.%d.%Y')
Time differences in days
[1] 16184 16132
```

if you have an error with the above, it is probably cuz your fd and ld are not of type character. then use

```
as.Date(as.character(ld),format = '%m.%d.%Y') - as.Date(as.character(fd),format = '%m.%d.%Y')
```

Comment: well, the fact is that there are 1037 dates, so I am looking for a way to calculate the difference without having to do it 1037 times.

Comment: i don't understand. you need to do only once - `as.Date(ld,format = '%m.%d.%Y')-as.Date(fd,format = '%m.%d.%Y')` where ld and fd can be as long as you want (almost)

Comment: oh you re right. I just undestood something completely diffenrent. now I get it. thanks

Comment: no prob. if my answer helped you, please consider accepting it.